# Is it possible to bake an image texture to a pure transparent background?

Tags: texture-baking

I have an image texture that has a transparent node in it and when I bake it to a new image, the parts that are supposed to be transparent are black.  Is there a way to create a new image in the image editor that is purely transparent?

This is the problem:

[image]